# iOS , Handle tableview property globally

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm using tableview in all classes of my project. I just want to remove some default property like table bouncing to all tableview. Instead of remove it in each and every class, is there any option to write single line code that reflects for tableview in all class?

Comment: Create your own tableView class and subclass it to all your app's tableView...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Extension like this.

```
extension UITableView{
  func setTableViewBasicProperties(){
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    //tableview's other propeties
  }
}
```

and simply call method into your ViewController:

```
yourtableView.setTableViewBasicProperties()
```

Comment: if my answer is helpful to you then accept it, so other also get help from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend UITableView class and modify the properties as well as add some methods for added functionality.`Extensions` add new functionality to an existing class, structure, enumeration, or protocol type. This includes the ability to extend types for which you do not have access to the original source code.

You can extend UITableView as

```
extension UITableView{
    func configureTableView(){
       self.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
       //modify other propeties of UITable View 
      }
 }
```

Now you can set these properties to each of tableview in any class as

```
self.yourtableView.configureTableView()
```